# How can I put PowerBI under a source code control?

Tags: git, version-control, powerbi, devops, powerbi-desktop

I need to make backups of Power BI reports under a source code control system (Visual Studio to git/devops) or other means that is not a simple file copy?

I tried Power BI version control based on Sharepoint but I encountered problems while configuring it

Comment: Have no idea, but place the answer, please, if you find a solution )

Comment: Check this out: [Source Control with Power BI - Can it be done?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCGd5qID-dY)

Comment: I have already watched, the solution is not yet available, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I found this article which may be useful, here is the links https://www.fourmoo.com/2019/07/23/setting-up-version-control-for-my-power-bi-desktop-files-pbix-with-no-additional-cost-part-1/ https://www.fourmoo.com/2019/08/06/using-version-control-with-power-bi-desktop-files-check-in-check-out-view-or-revert-to-previous-versions-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Power BI resources are:

Reports .rdls, rds,pbix,.. etc
The installation does not need to be in the SCM unless you need to add the web. config if there are some changes

to add them

Just easy to initiate a git repository in a folder and add those resources in this folder then push the changes
and  consider this is a large file git

To create the repository  check this [link](https://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html)

For Git large files check this [link](https://git-lfs.com/)

note changes in the files will not directly affect in the e server it is required to be uploaded to the power you may consider a pipeline for automating uploading files